# preg_match not returning match value when data is from csv

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a csv upload in my site now when I try to do pregmatch for the first row of the csv, it is returning empty. See the code below.

```
 $uploaded_file = $upload_dir . $_FILES['my_upload_file']['name'];
 $uploaded_content = file( $uploaded_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
 $regx_pattern = '/^(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)_/'; 
 $first_row = array_shift( $uploaded_content );
 $row_match = preg_match( $regx_pattern , $first_row, $matches );
 var_dump($matches);
```

Result:

```
array
    empty
```

But, if I declare `$first_row` as static value in my script by doing like this:

```
$first_row= 'nickname,nick_name_initial,nick_name_code';
```

It will return a match. Why isn't it returning a match when I'm checking it from my csv data? Anyone encountered this?

Comment: Could you show us the content of `$first_row` just after `array_shift`?

Comment: Hi, when array_shift the value of $first_row is ï»¿nickname,nick_name_initial,nick_name_code. I noticed it late that there is some special characters before the first string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ignore non alphanum and not quote characters at the begining of the string, you could do:

```
$regx_pattern = '/^[^\w"]*(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)_?/';
// $first_row = array_shift( $uploaded_content );
$first_row = 'ï»¿nickname,nick_name_initial,nick_name_code';
$row_match = preg_match( $regx_pattern , $first_row, $matches );
var_dump($matches);
```

**output:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "ï»¿nickname"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "nickname"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't return a match when you give the static value as you mentioned.

```
$regx_pattern = '/^(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)_/'; 
//$first_row = array_shift( $uploaded_content );
$first_row= 'nickname,nick_name_initial,nick_name_code';
$row_match = preg_match( $regx_pattern , $first_row, $matches );
var_dump($matches);
```

It won't work because in the regular expression you are expecting an underscore after the key and in the static value you given, for the key nickname there is no last underscore. You must have to make it optional as below.

```
$regx_pattern = '/^(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)(_)?/'; 
//$first_row = array_shift( $uploaded_content );
$first_row= 'nickname,nick_name_initial,nick_name_code';
$row_match = preg_match( $regx_pattern , $first_row, $matches );
var_dump($matches);
```

OR

There will be a chance that in the csv file you uploading may have a whitespace in the beginning. Because you are expecting the keys will be starting in the first letter itself ( ^).

Comment: Hi Jithin, there might be some special characters before it or maybe white space. How do i make it, that it will match the expression according to its position?

Comment: I removed the caret in the regex, so my new pattern is now /(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)_/. It works for me but i dont know if this is a good solution.

Comment: Hoping you got the whitespace at the starting.

You may need to trim $first_row to remove the whitespaces.

OR

Use the following regex
/^\s*(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)(_)?/
so that now its expects that there may whitespaces at the beginning

Comment: It's not really a white space because of this $uploaded_content = file( $uploaded_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES ); but rather it is a special character " ï»¿nick_name_test ". You see that " ï»¿ " before the nickname? That's why it will return false on preg_match. Isn't it a good idea to remove the caret?

Comment: As anyway you are parsing only a defined set of keys its okay to remove the caret.

Comment: My boss don't agree with removing caret in the regular expression, is there any other alternative so that it will just ignore the special characters before it?

Comment: /^\W*(nickname|nick_name|family_name|\"nickname|"family_name)/ This will skip the non word characters [^A-Za-z0-9_] at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
$htmlfile = file_get_contents($url);

$html = <<<HTML
echo $htmlfile;
HTML;
```

because you read and retain the content of the file, but that way it can't be processed

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input but I got the same thing, it is not matching.